# Is it possible to enroll emulator device to Android Management API for developing?

Tags: android, android-studio, mdm

I am trying to develop an android mobile device management system using Android Management API. However I'm having a hard time provisioning my emulated device to my enterprise. I'm currently working from home so I don't really have access to android hardware.

I've been following google's [Quick start guide](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb), and things went well until I have my QR code and tried to provision my emulated device.

```
Fully managed mode
In fully managed mode the entire device is managed and the device needs to be factory reset before setup. To set up a device in fully managed mode you need to use a QR code.

For devices running Android 7.0 or above:

1.Turn on a new or factory-reset device.
2.Tap the same spot on the welcome screen six times to enter QR code mode.
3.Connect to a WiFi network.
4.Scan the QR code.
For devices running Android 6.0:

1.Turn on a new or factory-reset device.
2.Follow the setup wizard and enter your Wi-Fi details.
3.When prompted to sign in, enter afw#setup.
4.Tap Next, and then accept the installation of Android Device Policy.
5.Scan the QR code.
```

The thing is, in android studio AVD, there is no welcome screen, nor can I bring it up by factory resetting. I have also tried afw#setup and work profiles but all are in vein.
Is it possible to enroll a virtual device to test out Android Management APIs?

Please if anyone succeeds let me know how.

P.S. I'm using macOS with an M1 chip.

Comment: Hi @Sorevan did you find your answer, how did you do it?